# Akka chunk size exception

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to make a singleRequest from Akka using this code:

```
val request = HttpRequest(
  method = HttpMethods.GET,
  uri = "url"
)
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(request)
val entityFuture: Future[HttpEntity.Strict] = responseFuture.flatMap(response => response.entity.toStrict(2.seconds))
entityFuture.map(entity => entity.data.utf8String)
```

However when I request a big json string I get the following exception.

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: HTTP chunk size exceeds the configured limit of 1048576 bytes
```

How do I configure this, I am not using Akka typed(I think), just this:

```
  implicit val system = ActorSystem() 
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer() 
  import system.dispatcher
```

Comment: Check the  config parameters here https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html

Comment: I have checked that, however I dont understand how to set the parameters when not using Akka typed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following configuration to increase the request size:

```
akka.http.parsing.max-chunk-size = 16m
```